# How to use container or generic variable in a query?

Tags: containers, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

It's possible to use string value in a Query?

I have this code in my Form init method:

```
container con;

select myTable
where myTable.MyFIeld == conPeek(con, 1);
//I would like to fill my stringEditControl
StringEdit.text(strFmt('%1', myTable.MyFIeld));
```

I have an error look like this:

> "The fields of type string container and unconstrained are not allowed in the WHERE expression."

How can I use the value string or container (in this case) in a query?

Thanks for your time,

enjoy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the string from container prior to using it is select statement:

```
MyTable   myTable;
container con;
str 50 strValue;

strValue = conPeek(con, 1);

select myTable
where myTable.MyField == strValue;

StringEdit.text(strFmt('%1', myTable.MyFIeld));
```

Comment: Hi Maxim Lazarev , I used this metod but I get the same error.

Comment: Try declaring `strValue` as `str50`  for example, or a better approach is to use EDT. I have updated the answer.